# How to bind multiple file uploads with model in web api?

Tags: .net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I can't see what's missing here.

I have a model that looks like this:

```cs
public class ModelDto
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    // ...
    public IList<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

It is used for a POST endpoint in Web Api, like this:

```cs
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseModel>> PostEndpoint([FromForm] ModelDto modelDto)
{
    // ...
}
```

When I POST with Postman, with Form-Data, and fields, including `Attachment[0]` as a file, I receive a model, complete with all other fields, but without any file.  But I do receive the file in the request.  If I look at this.Request.Form.Files, it's there, but it was not loaded as part of the model.

So, obviously, I can manually re-attach the list of files to the appropriate part of the model.  But why doesn't the binding work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it, so the problem was on the Postman side of how I wrote the request.

For arrays of text keys, the `[]` notation is used.  It must not be used for arrays of files.

So instead of sending `Attachments[0]` or `Attachments[]`, I just had to send `Attachments` as the key to each file.  Then the binding works fine.